# Add html to wrap views programaticly

Tags: 7, views, theming

I need to wrap field in views. I use views with module Responsive grid and have this html.

```
 <div class="services">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      <h3 class="services-heading" data-thmr="thmr_16"><div class="field-title-for-view" data-thmr="thmr_4 thmr_1">Responsive <span>html</span></div></h3>    
      <div class="services-img" data-thmr="thmr_16"><a href="/responsive-html" data-thmr="thmr_5 thmr_6 thmr_8"><img src="http://dvlk/sites/default/files/services_img_2.png" width="101" height="66" alt="" data-thmr="thmr_7"></a></div>    
      <p class="services-p" data-thmr="thmr_16"><span data-thmr="thmr_9" class="devel-themer-wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultrices sit amet diam eu accumsan.</span></p>
```

I want to have this html

```
<div class="services">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <article class="mycustomclass">
         <h3 class="services-heading" data-thmr="thmr_16"><div class="field-title-for-view" data-thmr="thmr_4 thmr_1">Responsive <span>html</span></div></h3>    
      <div class="services-img" data-thmr="thmr_16"><a href="/responsive-html" data-thmr="thmr_5 thmr_6 thmr_8"><img src="http://dvlk/sites/default/files/services_img_2.png" width="101" height="66" alt="" data-thmr="thmr_7"></a></div>    
      <p class="services-p" data-thmr="thmr_16"><span data-thmr="thmr_9" class="devel-themer-wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultrices sit amet diam eu accumsan.</span></p>      
    </article>
 </div>
```

I know that i should use this function hook_preprocess_views_view, hook_preprocess_views_view_fields or hook_preprocess_views_view_field but i don't know how to do it correctly. 
So how can i have this html **without creating *tpl.php file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in the views admin interface in the next way:

1. Exclude existing fields from display
2. Add new field Global: Custom text
3. Display new fields in Custom text filed using tokens

See example
[image]